# Python, Pandas: Add default for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

right now my dataframe is looking something like this:

```
date        |    type    |    value
2021-01-01  |    extern  |    17
2021-01-01  |    intern  |    19.5
2021-01-02  |    extern  |    104
2021-01-02  |    intern  |    8
2021-01-03  |    extern  |    17.4
2021-01-04  |    intern  |    34
```

As you may see, the dates *2021-01-03* and *2021-01-04* are missing rows, because neither of both have *extern* **and** *intern* values. I wonder if it's possible to turn this dataframe into something like this:

```
date        |    type    |    value
2021-01-01  |    extern  |    17
2021-01-01  |    intern  |    19.5
2021-01-02  |    extern  |    104
2021-01-02  |    intern  |    8
2021-01-03  |    extern  |    17.4
2021-01-03  |    intern  |    0
2021-01-04  |    intern  |    34
2021-01-04  |    extern  |    0
```

**Notes:**

- the amount of values in *type* is limited to - for example - these two (*extern* and *intern*). There is no other value that may pop up.

Hope someone might know a solution for this kind of situation!? Thanks for all our help and a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the missing combinations; at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git

import janitor

df.complete(["date", "type"], fill_value={"value": 0})

     date      type     value
0   2021-01-01  extern  17.0
1   2021-01-01  intern  19.5
2   2021-01-02  extern  104.0
3   2021-01-02  intern  8.0
4   2021-01-03  extern  17.4
5   2021-01-03  intern  0.0
6   2021-01-04  extern  0.0
7   2021-01-04  intern  34.0
```

Using Pandas' only, we can create unique values for columns 'A' and 'B", build a new MultiIndex, then reindex the dataframe:

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
[df.date.unique(), df.type.unique()], names=["date", "type"])

 new_index

 MultiIndex([('2021-01-01', 'extern'),
                ('2021-01-01', 'intern'),
                ('2021-01-02', 'extern'),
                ('2021-01-02', 'intern'),
                ('2021-01-03', 'extern'),
                ('2021-01-03', 'intern'),
                ('2021-01-04', 'extern'),
                ('2021-01-04', 'intern')],
           names=['date', 'type'])
```

Now, [set index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index), [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [reset index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
df.set_index(["date", "type"]).reindex(new_index, fill_value=0).reset_index()

    date    type    value
0   2021-01-01  extern  17.0
1   2021-01-01  intern  19.5
2   2021-01-02  extern  104.0
3   2021-01-02  intern  8.0
4   2021-01-03  extern  17.4
5   2021-01-03  intern  0.0
6   2021-01-04  extern  0.0
7   2021-01-04  intern  34.0
```

the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) is an abstraction of the above steps, with some more options, especially for nested combinations and completely new values.

Comment: Thank you! Took the 'pandas'-only solution and it worked perfectly!